# playframwork set response header globally

Tags: java, playframework, httpresponse

how can I set the respnose headers globally for my playframework project?
I don't want to add the stuff for each REST method.

```
    response().setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response().setHeader("Allow", "*");
    response().setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
    response().setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Referer, User-Agent");
```

This is what I add to each Method at the Moment.

Thanks

Comment: [that](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/SecurityHeaders) is what you need to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play supports [filters](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaHttpFilters), it's a way of modifying HTTP requests/responses globally.

Something like:

```
public class GlobalHeaders extends Filter {

@Inject
public GlobalHeaders(Materializer mat) {
    super(mat);
}

@Override
public CompletionStage<Result> apply(
        Function<Http.RequestHeader, CompletionStage<Result>> nextFilter,
        Http.RequestHeader requestHeader) {
    return nextFilter.apply(requestHeader).thenApply(result -> {

        return result.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
          .setHeader("Allow", "*")
          .setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS")
          .setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Referer, User-Agent");
    });
}
```

}

Comment: where do I have to do this?

Comment: see here https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaHttpFilters#Using-filters
implement Filters class and register it `play.http.filters=com.example.Filters`

Comment: got an error with Filter ... what do I have to import?

Comment: I've added my code above and a screesnhot with errors as well

Comment: no, that's all the info needed. what info are you missing?

Comment: thats woring, but be carefull you need playframework 2.5 and then its not setheader ... its withheader

Answer (score 1):

Another way for 2.8 is this: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/JavaActionsComposition

You implement an annotation:

```
@With(VerboseAnnotationAction.class)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface VerboseAnnotation {
  boolean someValue() default true;
}
```

and an Action:

```
public class VerboseAnnotationAction extends Action<VerboseAnnotation> {
  public CompletionStage<Result> call(Http.Request req) {
    // This is you're taking value from the annotation
    boolean parameterValue = configuration.someValue();

    // decorate the response after calling the controller
    return delegate.call(req)
       .thenApply(r -> r.withHeader("SomeHeaderName", parameterValue));
  }
}
```

Then you just use the annotation with the method or with the whole Controller class:

```
@VerboseAnnotation(false)
public Result verboseAnnotationIndex() {
  return ok("It works!");
}
```